# How delete file from fortran code?

Tags: linux, bash, file, shell, fortran

I need to delete a file from a `Fortran` code. I am on `ubuntu 12.04, x86_64`. I don't understand why the procedure described below does not work. Please help me to clarify the situation (actually, on some systems, it works, but not on mine).

There is another way: I can call directly unix command `rm -f file`, but I'd like to know what is wrong with my method. Thank you.

Step 1. make simple script del.sh and put it into ~/bin

```
$ cat del.sh
[ $# -ge 1 ] && rm -f $1
$ chmod u+x del.sh; mv del.sh ~/bin
```

Step 2. Fortran code, del.for:

```
character*100 cmd
character*30 file
call getarg(1,file)
write(cmd,100) file
100   format('source del.sh ',a30)
call system(cmd)
end
```

Step 3. Compile and run:

```
$ ifort -o del del.for
$ ./del file
```

Results:

```
sh: 1: source: not found
```

What is wrong? The simple 'source del.sh file' works, but not from Fortran code... that is confusing.

From the Fortran code:

```
100 format('del.sh ',a30)
100 format('bash del.sh ',a30)
```

work perfectly, but

```
100 format('sh del.sh ',a30)
```

does not work. I have `bash` installed, but no `csh`. Thank you.

Comment: Did you know that a file can also be deleted by opening it with status 'SCRATCH' and then closing it.  This is portable across all OSs and there is no need to mess with scripts or what the OS command is for deleting a file.

Comment: cup and @AlexanderVogt : thank you for the answers. Yes, Fortran can delete files, I know that. The idea of calling script from the Fortran code should make your programme more flexible: the script can be easily modified and adjusted to your needs without recompiling the project. For example, in stead of deleting file, I can backup it and so on. Also another my question was: why the described approach does not work? I am just curious...

Comment: the old f77 standard actually simply says "SCRATCH must not be specified with a named file".  I don't know how portable that really is to delete a named file that way?

Comment: @george: Good point.  Guess the best option is to open with status old and close with delete as suggested by AlexanderVogt.

Comment: @axion: Does it work if you add #!/bin/sh at the top of your script?  Does /bin/sh exist?

Comment: adding heading line as `#!/bin/sh` does not help and yes `/bin/sh` exists (sorry - did not notice your question earlier).

Answer (score 49):

Why not let Fortran do the work for you? This code is portable (compare cup's comment):

```
open(unit=1234, iostat=stat, file=file, status='old')
if (stat == 0) close(1234, status='delete')
```

Comment: Alexander and @cup, in any case, I think that deleting file within Fortran as you both have mentioned is, probably, a mush better style. Thank you.

Comment: The posted form is a good starting point, but has the problem, that it silently ignores errors.

Comment: Do I have to declare INTEGER stat in the preamble?

Comment: @Machinato Yes, you should

Answer (score 2):

`source` is a shell builtin that loads another script in the current process (as opposed to running it in a subprocess).

You have no need of `source` when invoking a script from Fortran, as you found out.  Both
`del.sh` and `bash del.sh` worked, and either of those represent the way you should be doing it.

Comment: Thank you, Jim. I believe that it is the best answer so far. So, 'loading script into current process' via source is a wrong intention/style and that is why it does not work (or should not work at least), correct? Of course, I want to execute the script, but not to load it. Interesting, that it worked on other machines... May I ask what is the difference between processes created by Fortran and shell? (and thank you for editing my question).

Comment: There is no difference, a process is a process.  It may have worked on other machines, possibly because the implementation invoked a shell to execute your command line, as opposed to running it directly. It's hard to tell without more details.

Answer (score 2):

The `system` call invokes the shell to execute your command, which shell depends on the system/environment. Since you get `sh: 1: source: not found`, the shell which is invoked doesn't understand the `source` command, which is a `bash` builtin. On Ubuntu, by default `/bin/sh` is linked to `/bin/dash`, not `/bin/bash`, and `dash` does not understand `source`. Instead, using the `.` (portable) builtin instead of `source`:

```
100   format('. del.sh ',a30)
```

should work, if `del.sh` is in your `$PATH`.

This is why I would think that these should all work:

```
100 format('sh del.sh ',a30)
100 format('bash del.sh ',a30)
100 format('del.sh ',a30)
```

But you have it differently? In that case, beats me :)

Comment: Interesting that `. del.sh`, `sh del.sh`, and `source del.sh` versions don't work and `bash del.sh`, `del.sh` works fine. It maybe only because of my configuration. I don't understand why it is so except Jim's answer. But you are right that we should start to dig with the error message: `sh: 1: source: not found`. I have tried many variants, for example `sh del.sh` does not work even from command line if `del.sh` is in `$PATH`, if I save the script locally then `sh` works. Thank you!

Comment: when you do "sh script", sh must  be on your path, but path is not searched for the script, it has to be in the current directory.  My opinion the safest approach (assuming linux) here is to make the script executable with an appropriate shebang line  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29 , then directly execute the script (do not source , do not invoke yet another sub shell ) ( ie the last of steaberts approaches )

Comment: @george: yes, that was my misunderstanding between: source, invoke a sub shell and execute. Also I believed that anything which works from command line (as `source del.sh`) must work when called with `system` command in Fortran. Apparently it may or may not work. I will check the shebang option - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So in your shell script, you don't specify a program in the first line.  Try adding:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

as the very first line in del.sh.  When bash starts it without that, it may be running the script with /bin/sh, not /bin/bash as you'd expect.  (I'm not able to confirm right now, but I know I've had trouble in the past if I use bash-specific code but forget to put the shebang at the top.)  When bash starts it with that line, it will see that it needs to be executed with bash instead.  Since your code appears to show that calling it as a bash argument directly works, I'd say this should fix your problem.
All the best.

Comment: user2600110, thank you for the answer. That is what I want - to understand why it does not work as expected. I tried to add the corresponding header lines (as you mentioned) to the script - it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
call system(trim(cmd))
```

Comment: The trim should not cause any difference in the `system` statement.