# dispose syntax error when using fortran open statement

Tags: file, fortran

I am opening a file which has to be deleted at the end. The following command complains about using `dispose`.

```
f = "espy.tmp";  h = "formatted";  r = "read" 
Open (newunit=u, file=f, form=h, action=r,  &
  status="old", dispose="delete")

lib/core.f:177:21:

     status="old", dispose="delete")
                 1
Error: Syntax error in OPEN statement at (1)
```

Comment: I'm wondering whether you're using an oder version of `gfortran` which doesn't yet know the `newunit` option. For example: I can't recreate this because mine doesn't know it yet.

Comment: I am using gcc-5.00. It is a nice feature. `newunit` is not what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Dispose` is a [non-standard compiler extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/fortran/2013-07/msg00108.html) (and not supported by your compiler). As described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668832/how-delete-file-from-fortran-code/18671521#18671521), the standard way to do this is to delete the file on closure:

```
f = "espy.tmp";  h = "formatted";  r = "read" 
Open (newunit=u, file=f, form=h, action=r,  &
  status="old")

close(u, status='delete')
```

Or, you could use temporary/scratch files (no filename):

```
f = "espy.tmp";  h = "formatted";  r = "read" 
Open (newunit=u, form=h, action=r,  &
  status="old", status='scratch')
```

Comment: I cannot use internal files as the file already exists and need to read it. Your first solution works as I need it to.